# TypeError: WAConnection is not a constructor using @adiwajshing/baileys in nodejs

Tags: node.js

`
const {WAConnection, MessageType} = require('@adiwajshing/baileys');

// create a connection
const conn = new WAConnection();

error:--
const conn = new WAConnection();
^

TypeError: WAConnection is not a constructor

Some time it run but there is problem
WARN [2023-03-09 09:55:15.787 +0000] (840): connect attempt 1 failed: Error: Unexpected server response: 404, retrying...
class: "Baileys"
error: {} `